# Manual Active-Active DynamoDB MultiRegion Replicas

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, replication, region

Trying to implement multi-region replication for DynamoDB. Very similar to Global Tables, except the major limitations:

1. need to be able to add more regions along the way.
2. make this work even when there is data in the tables.

Would want to rely on lambdas dynamo streams and probably event rules for periodic checks. Solution should support writes to either region just like in case with GlobalTables.

I was hoping to get help with algorithm that would ensure that the data is eventually consistent.

In my case amount of data inside tables would be very little.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

I think you can do this... Just get a list of records as they come in and then do a post to replica tables. You can do this either in lambda function or just a service that runs on a box some where

Comment: well, dynamo streams would definitely be an essential part of the solution, but my question was to get more details on the algorithm on how to achieve that. The algorithm should also make sure there are no infinite loops caused by replication. Also, how to handle addition of new replicas? And this is something not supported by DynamoDB GlobalTables.

Comment: You could add a “source_region” attribute to all items as you replicate them to other regions. When you’re consuming the stream, if that attribute is different than the region that you’re consuming the stream in, then don’t replicate it to other regions. (This is assuming that the source region replicated to all regions rather than chaining regions together.)

Comment: How to handle the case when the object was created in one region, but then updated in another one?